# use wget for the most updated file on http server

Tags: windows, command-line, wget

I need to download the most updated files with the name suite.

I am using windows server to run the command lines.

I wrote the following command but not sure of how to get the most updated one

```
wget -r --cut-dirs=2 --no-check-certificate --no-parent -A *suite*.zip https://myip/
```

The remote folders files are:

```
[   ]   file-client.win.RC1.4.140929.zip            29-Sep-2014 15:20   2.3G     
[   ]   file-client.11_3_1.win.RC1.140813.zip       13-Aug-2014 20:43   2.3G     
[   ]   file-nodb.11_3_1.win.RC1.1.140814.zip       14-Aug-2014 16:20   2.8G     
[   ]   file-nodb.11_3_1.win.RC1.2.140820.zip       20-Aug-2014 13:02   2.8G     
[   ]   file-nodb.11_3_1.win.RC1.140813.zip         13-Aug-2014 20:52   2.8G     
[   ]   file-suite.is_11_3_1.win.RC1.1.140814.zip   14-Aug-2014 16:03   5.6G     
[   ]   file-suite.is_11_3_1.win.RC1.2.140820.zip   20-Aug-2014 12:46   5.6G     
[   ]   file-suite.is_11_3_1.win.RC1.3.140917.zip   17-Sep-2014 18:23   5.6G     
[   ]   file-suite.is_11_3_1.win.RC1.140813.zip     13-Aug-2014 20:35   5.6G     
[   ]   file.11_3_1.win.RC1.1.140814.zip            14-Aug-2014 16:29   646M     
[   ]   file.11_3_1.win.RC1.2.140820.zip            20-Aug-2014 13:12   646M     
[   ]   file.11_3_1.win.RC1.140813.zip              13-Aug-2014 21:02   646M
```

Comment: Does [How to wget the more recent file of a directory](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15040132) or [wget newest file in another server's folder](http://stackoverflow.com/q/18168523) help?

Comment: @DavidPostill Not really. The first one refers to the files being sorted by modification date - not my case and the second one refers to the same file being updated. In my case it's not going to be the same file. A new file

Comment: You will need use techniques similar to those in @DavidPostill's link: retrieve the directory list to a local file, then perform some parsing and sorting on it, and thereby identify each file group and the latest revision in it. I won't pretend it's easy, because the file naming structure is complex, and probably not worth doing for a list that short: you are better off selecting each file manually.

Comment: what do you mean by the last sentence? I thought to go over the list and parse the date

Comment: @DavidPostill maybe I am missing something about the -N usage.

Comment: I thought my meaning was clear. The file names seem to consist of an indeterminate number of dot-separated fields, followed by a release date code and `.zip`. The release code is a lot easier to sort on than an Ascii date, but more difficult to isolate for sorting. Plus, the file date may not always coincide with the release date, though it does in your list above. Whatever you do, it will be a lot more work than looking at the list and picking the files you want.

Comment: @AFH Thanks. Correct. but it's not the requirements as it's part of jenkins job to take the last updated file :(